# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to call a form in php with Javascript but for some reason,

```
document.getElementById("form1").submit()
```

returns null when it should returns the form1.

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function verificar(){
        ........
        if(certoCarga && certoKm)
            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Php:

```
    <div id="quadro">
       <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="alteraAuxController.php">
            ....
            <div id="rodape" align="center">
                    <input type="hidden" value="altera" name ="post1">
                    <input type="button" name="alterar" id="btn2" value="Alterar" onclick="verificar()">
            </div>
       </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like an on ready issue.  `$(document).ready(function() {...`

Answer (score 0):

You can put your script tag code just above the closing of body tag if its currently placed in HEAD tag